# Execute tkinter button without clicking on it

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, calculation

I have a Python GUI which makes a simple calculation. Running the main file called `gui.py` opens up a graphical interface. I would like to open the graphical interface and automatically click on the `Kjør beregning button`. (it means "Run calculation" in norwegian).

`Button` is defined the following way in `gui.py`:

```
beregn_btn = tk.Button(av_beregn, text="Kjør beregning", font=bold, command=self._beregn)
```

I'd like to add some code here to invoke calculation, if that is possible:
So far without luck.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Kjører program
root = KL_mast()
hovedvindu = Hovedvindu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just call `hovedvindu._beregn()` before `root.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this (small example that invokes the button without a click):

```
import tkinter as tk

def beregn():
    print('invoke_button called by button clicked or invoked')
    
def invoke_button():
    """ this does not call beregn, but instead invokes the beregn_btn"""
    beregn_btn.invoke()
    root.after(2000, invoke_button)
    
root = tk.Tk()
beregn_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Kjør beregning", command=beregn)
beregn_btn.pack()

root.after(2000, invoke_button)   # start the invocation demo

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I rejected your edit because It seemed to ask and answer a (related), but different question; my suggestion is to ask a new question if it is necessary.