# Excetue buttons in a new tkinter window which is called within the program (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, calculation

I have a Python GUI which makes a simple calculation. Running the main file called gui.py opens up a graphical interface. I open the graphical interface and automatically click on the Kjør beregning and Resultater buttons. (it means "Run calculation" and "Results" in norwegian).
It provides me a new window which is called Resultater and has it's own buttons. Question is how I call functions or execute buttons in the new window without clicking.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Kjører program
root = KL_mast()
hovedvindu = Hovedvindu(root)
# starts calculation then invokes results button
hovedvindu._beregn()
hovedvindu._resultater()

root.mainloop()
```

hovedvindu._resultater() opens a new frame called Resultater and I'd like to invoke functions there after opening it. Here is Resultater frame and how Tabell button is defined which I'd like to open with adding extra code to the one above just before root.mainloop()

```
class Resultater(tk.Frame):
"""Vindu for resultater."""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Initialiserer vindu."""
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.pack(fill="both")

    tabell_btn = tk.Button(knapper_frame, text="Tabell", font=bold,
                           command=self.M._tabell)
```

Here is my previous question connected to the same program if that is any help.

[Execute tkinter button without clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892616/execute-tkinter-button-without-clicking-on-it/64893048?noredirect=1#comment114909894_64893048)

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter button have a method called invoke witch calls the button's callback, and returns what that function returns and has no effect if the button is disabled or if there is no callback.To invoke a button in another fram just use the button's name

**here is how to use invoke:**

```
import tkinter as tk

#Onclick Method1
def OnClick():
    #Invoking button on seperate frame
    btn2.invoke()

#Onclick Method 2
def ResulatorOnClick():
    print('btn2 has been clicked')

master = tk.Tk()

Resulator = tk.Frame(master)
Resulator.pack()

btn1 = tk.Button ( master, width=40,height =20, command=OnClick)
btn1.pack()

btn2 = tk.Button ( Resulator, width=40,height =20, command=ResulatorOnClick)
btn2.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Output: `btn2 has been clicked`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works perfectly however it does not solve my issue. I'd like to invoke a button which is in the "Resultater" frame not in "hovedvindu". "Resultater" frame is opened by calling hovedvindu._resultater(). Looking at your example it would be like: btn1.invoke() opens a new frame which has a button called btn2 and I'd like to invoke that one.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. Invoke works with all the buttons in "Hovedvindu" (main window) but I get an error msg when I try invoke with buttons on Resultater window. And the error says it does not have the button as attribute. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\_Data\UDK05\gui.py", line 2793, in <module>
    Resultater.tabell_btn.invoke()
AttributeError: type object 'Resultater' has no attribute 'tabell_btn'